# Accessing/Using the GIthub secret of a repository in another repsository as a Admin

Tags: github, github-actions

Being a admin i want to access the github secret of application repositories and perform some githubactions from the "global admin repository" code

So i want to know if there is way to use /reference the secrets deifned in the "application repositories" inside my "global admin repository" workflow file?

Comment: Maybe you should consider using [organization level secrets](https://docs.github.com/en/codespaces/managing-codespaces-for-your-organization/managing-encrypted-secrets-for-your-repository-and-organization-for-github-codespaces#adding-secrets-for-an-organization) ?

Comment: No, the token will have the same name and has to be set at repository level

Comment: Let me know if I understood correctly: You want to set secret in specific repositories (inside the same organization) using workflows from a specific organization repository?

Comment: No, i have the secrets already set , i want to use that secret defined in 1 repsoitory as a env variable in other repository workflow via guthub actions with in the organization

Comment: No you can't do that. You need to move the secret to be an org secret and then you can assign the secret to the different repositories that need access to it.

Answer (score 0):

**There is no way to grant a repository access to the secrets of another repository.**

The only way to create secrets which are shared across repos through org level secrets. These can then be assigned to other repositories. Each repository can choose to override that secret, **but that overridden secret isn't available to the other repositories**.

If each repository needs a unique value for the secret there is a hack for this.

You can create a `APPNAME_SECRETNAME` secret at the org level and then assign that to the specific application repo as well as the global admin repo. Then in your YAML file, map the secret to a common name:

```
variables:
  SECRETNAME: ${{ secrets.APPNAME_SECRETNAME }}
```

That way the secret is both accessible to the global admin repo and the application repo, yet still available through a standardized name in the workflow steps, composite steps and reusable workflows.